# How to read PowerShell StdOut

Tags: c, powershell, stdout

I have code to invoke `CreateProcess()` and get the handles for StdIn & StdOut.
I have used it with CMD and it works fine. However, I started PowerShell
with it and PowerShell did not play nice. It basically exploited my program
and took over the thread.

This led me to debug of course and I found that as soon as the `ReadFile()`
function reads PowerShells output, it's all over. Interesting.

So my question is: In what format does PowerShell send output to StdOut?

I heard it talks in "Objects", but it seems to output raw machine code.

```c
DWORD WINAPI threadRead(HANDLE *cmdStd_OUT_RD) {
    char *chBuff = malloc(READ_BUFFER_SM);
    int check = 0;
    for (;;) {
        dwRead = 0;  //Global Variable
        check = 0;
        memset(chBuff, 0, READ_BUFFER_SM);
        puts("Reading..\n");
        check = ReadFile(*cmdStd_OUT_RD, chBuff, READ_BUFFER_SM, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (check || dwRead > 0) {
            printf("Display: %s\n", chBuff);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, Is there another `Read` function that is safe for PowerShell?

**Edit:** I feel like it is sending bytes so might try using a `void`. Will update after.

**Edit:** No, it still takes over. Guess `ReadFile()` cannot read its StdOut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6?

And try this:

```
$OutputVariable = (Shell command) | Out-String
```

or

```
"$params = "/verify $pc /domain:hosp.uhhg.org"
start-process "netdom.exe" $params -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait"
```

Comment: Sorry mate, long week,  I'll give you props now. yes, I found running scripts instead would be wiser. cheers.